# Looking for some insight on level mangment

Tags: level-design, starling

So, i'm creating this little music game as and exerciseand want to do it as "Correct" as possible.

The game works like this:

- The player gets a short melody played to them ("C4","D4","E4","C4")
- Then the player has to play it back.
- The notes in each level are at the movment stored in arrays as strings, and each level has a class(Level1, Level2 etc...).

I'm thinking this can be difficult to manage as a create more complex levels. And I really want to be able to add Levels via the internet without having to update the app.

Would it be better to have a "LevelMangager" that loads inn XML data on runtime?

I'm using the starling framework and i want it to be able to run on Mobile to.

As you probably can tell i'm fairly new to game dev. so all insight is appreciated

Comment: There's generally no one right way to do anything (this included), so these sorts of questions tend to be discussion-oriented. They're better asked on a forum, like [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net). That said, I'd say you probably don't want each level to be its own *class*, but rather have many instances of one class ("Level") and load the notes from a file.

Comment: I sorta disagree with this close reason; there is an objective answer to the specific question asked here. `Would it be better to have a "LevelMangager" that loads inn XML data on runtime?` Better than having each level as a separate class, yes. The BEST approach, well that is more debatable and could result in a non-productive discussion.